# Will libraries installed to my "base" system Python be available in a virtualenv?

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

I'm new to python, so please be gentle.

In learning python and writing my first few scripts, I quickly glossed over any tutorial sections on `virtualenv`, figuring it wouldn't provide me any benefit in my nascent stage.

I proceeded to hack away, installing packages as I went with `pip3 install package`

Now I've built something that is potentially useful to my organization, and I'd like to share it. In this case, I want to distribute it as a windows executable.

Before building this distribution, I figure it's now time to take the next leap from individual scripts to proper python projects. It seems like `virtualenv` should be part of that.

Given that I've installed a number of packages to my "base" python environment: in order to do development in a "clean" virtual environment, do I need to somehow "revert" my base python environment (i.e. uninstall all non-standard packages), or will `virtualenv` shield a project within a virtual environment from non-standard packages installed to my "base" environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the `venv` module there is `--system-site-packages` flag that will grant the created virtual environment access to the system-wide site-packages directory:

```
  --system-site-packages
                         Give the virtual environment access to the system
                         site-packages dir.
```

Comment: So the default behavior (i.e. without that flag set) would be that the virtual environment does not have access to the system site-packages dir?

Answer (score 1):

Go install [VirtualEnvWrapper](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper) first. After that, create a new virtualenv, activate it, and run pip freeze. You should see nothing in there because nothing is installed. Deactivate the env to go back to your 'Base' environment and pip freeze again. You will see all the installs you have.

A best practice is to create a requirements.txt file and version control it so everyone can use the same versions of the same packages. If you don't want to do this, simply activate your new virtual env and pip install everything you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify separately the required libraries and check if they are installed and if not then you can install them automatically.

Have a look at:

https://packaging.python.org/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned in the answer by DeepSpace, the `--system-site-packages` flag will grant the created virtual environment access to the system-wide site-packages directory.

If the virtual environment has been created, go to `$HOME/.venv/[name_of_your_environment]/pyvenv.cfg` and change the line `include-system-site-packages = false` to `include-system-site-packages = true`, to enable access to packages installed in the base environment.