# What packages are pulled into a new python virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm currently having an issue when having to install a python package via apt-get, and having it available in my python virtualenv. The developer of the package has indicated installing the package does not work via pip, and recommends installing via apt-get.

So I installed the .deb package and it installed the python modules into /usr/lib/python3/site-packages, as I expected. If I run python3, the interpreter indicates it's Python 3.5, and the command `import apt` succeeds. So far so good.

Now, I create a new virutal environment `virutalenv -p /usr/bin/python3 /home/me/python3_venv`

So then I enter the virtualenv (`source ~/python3_venv/bin/activate`) and run the python interpreter. The interpreter reports that it's running Python 3.5 (the default for Ubuntu 16.04).

However, `import apt` fails with `No module name 'apt'`

As I understand it, when the venv is created, it pulls in all the packages (or has reference to them?).

I did discover that under `/usr/lib` there are several directories for the different versions of Python. IE `python3`, `python3.5`, `python3.6`, `python2.7`, `python2`.  None of them are symlinks. They are all regular directories. So I'm not sure what resources virtualenv is grabbing when it creates a new env.

Comment: You can use `virutalenv --system-site-packages -p /usr/bin/python3 /home/me/python3_venv `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will libraries installed to my "base" system Python be available in a virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49364776/will-libraries-installed-to-my-base-system-python-be-available-in-a-virtualenv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/), you can find packages installed in a virtual environment in `ENV/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages/`, where `ENV` is the location of your environment.

In my installation, the following files are present:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 debian debian  126 Mar 19 22:50 easy_install.py
-rw-r--r--  1 debian debian  315 Mar 19 22:50 easy_install.pyc
drwxr-xr-x 10 debian debian 4096 Mar 19 22:50 pip
drwxr-xr-x  2 debian debian 4096 Mar 19 22:50 pip-9.0.2.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  4 debian debian 4096 Mar 19 22:50 pkg_resources
drwxr-xr-x  5 debian debian 4096 Mar 19 22:50 setuptools
drwxr-xr-x  2 debian debian 4096 Mar 19 22:50 setuptools-39.0.1.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  4 debian debian 4096 Mar 19 22:50 wheel
drwxr-xr-x  2 debian debian 4096 Mar 19 22:50 wheel-0.30.0.dist-info
```

If you want to use the system site packages add the `--system-site-packages` option such as:

```
virutalenv --system-site-packages -p /usr/bin/python3 /home/me/python3_venv
```

The documentation says:

> If you build with virtualenv `--system-site-packages ENV`, your virtual environment will inherit packages from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (or wherever your global site-packages directory is).